# Accessing spritenodes created in a for loop?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm building a game where obstacles continue to appear on screen as the player proceeds.Whenever the obstacles move outside of the camera's view they are removed and new are spawned.

I have a function which is called once in `didMoveToView()` , and once in the `update()` function inside this if statement:

```
if theCamera.containedNodeSet().count < 2 {}
```

This is the function:

```
 func addNewBlocks(number: Int, playerPosition: CGPoint) {


    if existingBlocks.count == 0 {
        updatePointArray(number, playerPosition: playerPosition)

        for index in 0...3 {

            let block = Obstacle()
            block.position = pointArray[index]
            block.name = "block\(index)"
            self.addChild(block)
            existingBlocks.append(block)
            print("adding blocks")
        }

    } else if existingBlocks.count > 0 {
        for index in 0...3 {
            self.childNodeWithName("block\(index)")?.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

It takes two parameters: A number- the number off obstacles to be spawned and the current player position.

My problem is that after having initially added obstacles in `didMoveToView()` I am unable  to remove the obstacles.
What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try use this to remove the nodes that aren't in the screen:

```
func didSimulatePhysics() {
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName(@"YOUR_NODE_NAME", usingBlock: {
    (node: SKNode, stop: Bool) -> Void in 
    if !CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), node.position) {
        node.removeFromParent()
    }
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should remove every non visible node.

```
private func removeNodesOutsideTheCamera() {
    self.children
        .filter { self.camera?.containedNodeSet().contains($0) == false }
        .forEach { $0.removeFromParent() }
}
```